# Godot how to fix rotation precision errors

Tags: godot, gdscript

I have a skeleton that my program rotates every frame. The rotation angle and axis is calculated using a starting direction vector (the bone position to the start position of its tip) and an ending direction vector (the bone position to the end position of its tip). The bones of the skeleton are rotated completely from the starting vector to the ending vector each frame. For the first 70 frames everything is fine and it rotates correctly. However, after that point, there are visible errors in the rotations. Each frame the error gets bigger and bigger until the rotation is completely wrong. I think this happens because of a precision error that causes this error to accumulate.

In the Godot docs it says:

> If a transform is rotated every frame, it will eventually start deforming over time. This is unavoidable.

> There are two different ways to handle this. The first is to orthonormalize the transform after some time (maybe once per frame if you modify it every frame):

To fix this issue I tried this:

```
transform.orthonormalized()
```

Which didn't seem to change anything, the errors were still there.

I was thinking of using the `.look_at()` method instead of rotating by an axis and angle, but I'm not sure if the precision errors would be there or not. Also, I'm not sure how to call that method on a bone of a skeleton.

What's the best way to fix this problem?

Comment: By the way, in case you missed it, `orthonormalized` returns a new transform. It does not modify the transform in place. However, I don't think it is the solution for this particular case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

---

### New Answer

*So you are dealing with physics…*

Let us rebuild the transform instead. We can extract the parts we need from the transform we have:

```
var start_location := transform.origin
var start_rotation := transform.basis.get_rotation_quat()
var start_scale := transform.basis.get_scale()
```

And you have a rotation you want to apply, keeping the other parts. So
I think that would be:

```
var new_location := transform.origin
var new_rotation := transform.basis.get_rotation_quat() * rotation
var new_scale := transform.basis.get_scale()
```

*Or you need to put `rotation * transform.basis.get_rotation_quat()` instead.*

And we build a transform from that, which I believe would be like this:

```
var new_transform := Transform(
    Basis(
        transform.basis.get_rotation_quat() * rotation
    ).scaled(transform.basis.get_scale()),
    transform.origin
)
```

And, if that does not get rid of the accumulated error, this should:

```
var new_transform := Transform(
    Basis(
        (transform.basis.get_rotation_quat() * rotation).normalized()
    ).scaled(transform.basis.get_scale()),
    transform.origin
)
```

---

### Old Answer

*This answer assumes you are making programmatic animations.*

Create start and end rotations (either quaternions or axis angle), and each frame create a new transform using an interpolated rotation from the end points. That is, you want the a transform that represents the rotation from the start of the motion, not the rotation from the prior frame.

---

For the interpolation, you probably want to use **the ratio of elapsed time over total time as weight**. And by that I mean that you would divide the time since the animation started over the total time the animation must take.

So, let us say, the animation started at `start_time`, and must take `total_time` to complete. At the instant `current_time`, you have:

```
elapsed_time = current_time - start_time
```

And the weight would be `elapsed_time/total_time`, which is:

```
(current_time - start_time)/total_time
```

I don't know how you are handling time. However, be aware that if you are using something like `OS.get_ticks_msec()` for example, which gives you milliseconds as an integer, then you would have an integer division when you want a float between `0.0` and `1.0` for the interpolation. So you would need to cast to float before dividing.

---

Similarly, if you want to apply the rotation to an original transform, do not apply incremental rotations each frame. Instead each frame combine the original transform with the rotation from the start of the motion to the current frame.

Since the rotations would not be based on the prior frame, the errors would not accumulate.

Comment: This is what I tried, but I still get the same results:                                                                  `var start = Quat(start_transform.basis.orthonormalized())

   var end = Quat(axis.normalized(), angle)

   var interpolation = start.slerp(end, 1)

   var new_transform = Transform(interpolation) * start_transform`

Comment: @DB I think you don't want `orthonormalized` at all. Also, isn't `start.slerp(end, 1)`  the same as `end`? I suppose it is different in your actual code, but I'd expect the time computation there.

Comment: I was calling `orthonormalized()` because otherwise this error would appear: `Basis must be normalized in order to be casted to a Quaternion. Use get_rotation_quat() or call orthonormalized() if the Basis contains linearly independent vectors.` I'll try using `get_rotation_quat()` instead.

Comment: You're probably right about `start.slerp(end, 1)` being the same as `end`. I wasn't sure how interpolation worked so I just put 1 as the weight. Could you explain what you meant when you said "using the ration of elapsed time over total time as weight"?

Comment: @DB I have expanded the answer.

Comment: I think I misunderstood what interpolation does. In my program, the bones of the skeleton are completely rotated from the start position to the end position every frame. Because of this I don't handle time and I just do the rotation every tick of the physics process. I'm not sure if interpolation makes sense in my case because of that.

Answer (score 0):

In combination with Theraot's answer above, I also found that resetting the Transform before calculating the rotation axis and angle helped to remove precision errors.

Something like:

```
skeleton.set_bone_pose(bone, Transform.IDENTITY)
```